# separate tokens in batch file

Tags: batch-file, dos

I have the following pice of code to get the first token of each file but it does not work. Please let me know what is wrong and also How I can fetch each other token of the line individually.

MY tab separated txt file is something like below:

```
ABC     1000     GHY_GGG
ADD     2000     
ABCSS     3000     JJY_GGG
```

My code below:

```
for /f "tokens=* usebackq delims= " %%a in ("%TraderWorkspaceFile%") do (
set line=%%a

call :processToken
)
goto :eof

:processToken

  for /f "tokens=1 delims= " %%f in ("%line%") do (      
   echo Got one token: %%f
  )

goto :eof
```

Thanks!

Comment: All problem reports should have smallest code sample that exhibits the problem (yours does), expected behaviour (again, you provide this) and _actual_ behaviour (nope, can't see that anywhere) :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The FOR /F command read *lines* of the file and separate they in *tokens* in accordance with "tokens= delims=" option. By default, "tokens" refer to just the first token in the line and "delims" include spaces and tabs (if they are not given). This FOR command:

```
for /f "usebackq" %%a in ("%TraderWorkspaceFile%") do echo %%a
```

would show:

```
ABC
ADD
ABCSS
```

whereas

```
for /f "tokens=2 usebackq" %%a in ("%TraderWorkspaceFile%") do echo %%a
```

would show:

```
1000
2000
3000
```

Please note that "delims= " is the same as the default value, so is useless, but "delims=" (no delims) is a trick that encloses in the first token the entire line.

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%TraderWorkspaceFile%") do (
set line=%%a
call :processToken
)
goto :eof

:processToken
  for /f "tokens=1 delims= " %%f in ("%line%") do (      
   echo Got one token: %%f
  )
goto :eof
```

would correctly show the first token *of every line*, although:

```
:processToken
  for /f %%f in ("%line%") do (      
   echo Got one token: %%f
  )
goto :eof
```

would do exactly the same thing...

You may get also individual space-or-tab-separated tokens via the parameters of the subroutine this way:

```
:processLine
echo First token: %1, second token: %2, third one: %3
goto :eof
```

that must be called this way (instead of call :processToken):

```
call :processLine %line%
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Aacini.. helped a lot!!

Comment: Also, is there a way to count number of tokens in a line ?

Comment: If the tokens have not wild-cards (* ?) nor delimiters (, ; =), the counting is immediate: **set n=0** followed by **for %%a in (%line%) do set /a n+=1**

Answer (score 2):

You say your file is `<tab>` separated, but it looks to me like your "delims" option is set to a `<space>`. If I am correct, then you can fix your problem by changing the space after "delims=" to a tab. Or better yet, if none of your values have spaces then you can simply remove the delims option altogether since the default delimiters are `<space>` and `<tab>`.

Assuming you can get the first token sorted out, then it is simple to extend your code to parse out all 3 tokens. Simply change to "tokens=1-3". Token 1 will be in %%f, token 2 in %%g, and token 3 in %%h.

By the way, I don't understand why you are using 2 loops. It seems like you can parse out the tokens directly in the first FOR loop. Unless the code you posted is a simplification of your actual code and you plan on doing something with the whole line ;)